# How to link menu when I have multiple Controller in my Application? Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, menubar

I am beginner in CI. I am developing an application in CI in which I have more then 1 controller like studentmaster, feesmaster, usermaster, etc and also different view associate with them. So How can I set route and menu in CI? means How can I create menu with different controller.

Comment: Check this may be useful to you http://oliversmith.io/technology/2011/08/27/easy-menu-formatting-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url("studentmaster"); ?>">Student Master</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url("feesmaster"); ?>">Fees Master</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url("usermaster"); ?>">User Master</a></li>
</ul>
```

Put the above code in any common file and include that file in every controller.